# Ruby - fork, exec, detach .... do we have a race condition here?

Tags: ruby, cygwin

Simple example, which doesn't work on my platform (`Ruby 2.2`, `Cygwin`):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
backtt = fork { exec('mintty','/usr/bin/zsh','-i') }
Process.detach(backtt)
exit
```

This tiny program (when started from the shell) is supposed to span a terminal window (mintty) and then get me back to the shell prompt.

However, while it DOES create the mintty window, I don't have a shell prompt afterwards, and I can't type anything in the calling shell.

But when I introduce a small delay before the detach, either using 'sleep', or by printing something on stdout, it works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
backtt = fork { exec('mintty','/usr/bin/zsh','-i') }
sleep 1
Process.detach(backtt)
exit
```

Why is this necessary?

BTW, I'm well aware that I could (from the shell) do a

```
mintty /usr/bin/zsh -i &
```

directly, or I could use system(`...... &`) from inside Ruby, but this is not the point here. I'm particularily interested in the `fork/exec/detach` behaviour in Ruby. Any insights?

Comment: Although no specialist for Ruby, and not knowing Cygwin at all, this situation sounds very familiar to me (comming from c(++)):

This script is to short :-) - what happens if you put the sleep after detach and before exit?

Answer (score 6):

**Posting as an answer, because it is too long for a comment**

Although I am no specialist in Ruby, and do not know Cygwin at all, this situation sounds *very* familiar to me, coming from C/C++.

This script is too short, so the parent of the parent completes, while the grandchild tries to start.

What would happen if you put the sleep after detach and before exit?

If my theory is correct, it should work too. Your program exits before any (or enough) thread-switching happens.

I call such problems "interrupted hand shaking". Although this is psychology terminology, it describes what happens.

Sleep "gives up the time slice", leading to thread-switching,

Console output (any file I/O) runs into semaphores, also leading to thread switching.

If my idea is correct, it should also work, if you dont "sleep", just count to 1e9 (depending on the speed of computation) because then preemptive multitasking makes even the thread-switch itself not giving up the CPU.

So it is an error in programming (IMHO: race condition is philosophical in that case), but it will get hard to find "who" is responsible. There are many things involved.

Comment: Indeed, putting the sleep after detach works! Thanks a lot! Of course I would prefer a more reliable mechanism to fight a race condition, but at least this one seems to be practical.

Comment: Oops, sorry to say, but your solution did NOT help. I made a mistake when editing and did not comment out the first sleep. If I do it exactly as you said, and sleep instead **after** the detach, it doesn't work.

Comment: so my assumption is not correct, it was just an idea, because looked familiar, thats why I wanted only to comment, not answer, - no idea how to remove the '50'

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Process.html#method-c-fork):

> `Process::detach` prevents this **by setting up a separate Ruby thread** whose sole job is to reap the status of the process pid when it terminates.

*NB:* I can’t reproduce this behaviour on any of available to me operating systems, and I’m posting this as an answer just for the sake of formatting.

Since `Process.detach(backtt)` transparently creates a thread, I would suggest you to try:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
backtt = fork { exec('mintty','/usr/bin/zsh','-i') }
#                     ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
Process.detach(backtt).join
exit
```

This is no hack by any mean (as opposite to silly `sleep`,) since you are likely aware of that the underlying command should return more-or-less immediately. I am not a guru in cygwin, but it might have some specific issues with threads, so, let this thread to be handled.

Comment: I can not use `join` here, because the underlying command does **not** return immediately, but rather is supposed to run for a long time - hours or days - as can be seen from the `-i` switch which is passed to `zsh` (meaning "open an interactive shell"). Actually, I don't think it makes sense to use mintty for a program which is supposed to be non-interactive, does it?

Comment: Indeed. Please disregard the above, I for unknown reason decided that `mintty` will detach the underlying process itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm neither a Ruby nor a Cygwin guy, so what I propose here may not work at all. Anyways: I guess, you're not even hitting a Ruby or Cygwin specific bug here. In a program called "start" I've written in C many years ago, I hit the same issue. Here is a comment from the start of the function void daemonize_now():

```
/*
 * This is a little bit trickier than I expected: If we simply call
 * setsid(), it may fail! We have to fork() and exit(), and let our
 * child call setsid().
 *
 * Now the problem: If we fork() and exit() immediatelly, our child
 * will be killed before it ever had been run. So we need to sleep a
 * little bit. Now the question: How long? I don't know an answer. So
 * let us being killed by our child :-)
 */
```

So, he strategy is this: Let the parent wait on it's child (that can be done immediately before the child actually had a chance to do anything) and then let the child do the detaching part. How? Let it create a new process group (it will be reparented to the init process). That's the setsid() call for, I'm talking about in the comment. It will work something like this (C-Syntax, you should be able to lookup the correct usage for Ruby and apply the needed changes yourself):

```
parentspid = getpid();
Fork = fork();
if (Fork) {
    if (Fork == -1) { // fork() failed
        handle error
    } else { // parent, Fork is the pid of the child
        int tmp; waitpid(0, &tmp, 0);
    }
} else { // child
    if (setsid() == -1) {
        handle error - possibly by doing nothing
        and just let the parent wait ...
    } else {
        kill(parentspid, SIGUSR1);
    }
    exec(...);
}
```

You can use any signal, that terminates the process (i.e. SIGKILL). I used SIGUSR1 and installed a signal handler that exit(0)s the parent process, so the caller gets a success message. Only caveat: You get a success even if the exec fails. However, that is a problem that can't really be worked around, since after a successful exec you can't signal your parent anything anymore. And since you don't know when the exec will have failed (if it fails), you're back at the race condition part.